# asp page doesn't see the javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

It doesn't see the function GetValue(), and the compilation error for the page is:

> CS1061: 'register_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue'
>   and no extension method 'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type
>   'register_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Relevant part from the aspx file

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUsername" runat="server" Width="180px" OnTextChanged="GetValue()" 
</asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript file include

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="scripts/register.js"></script>
```

Javascript file:

```
function GetValue() {
  alert('function used');
}
alert('js file used');
```

[image]

One thing I noticed: when i remove `OnTextChanged="GetValue()"` i get the alert `"js file used"`.

it's not about the javascript file, it's fine, i think the aspx page doesn't see the function name. this is my first time i use js with asp.net, sorry if i missed any details.

Comment: OnTextChanged needs a server side function not client side.

Comment: all i want is when the text changes in the username field, the js function gets called, can you please tell me what should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your client side function to client's onBlur event from server side code or in tag itself.

```
TextBoxUsername.Attributes["onBlur"] = "GetValue()";
```

Remove it from `OnTextChanged`

OnTextChange is executed on server i.e. the function should be written in code behind with `AutoPostback=true`.

Comment: it tells me i have to w8 5 mins

Answer (score 1):

Try using onchange="GetValue()" which should fire when the textbox loses focus.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUsername" runat="server" Width="180px" onchange="GetValue()" 
    </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: that also seems to be working, thanks alot for your help. strangely `onchange` doesn't appear in the dropdown list of suggestions in VS.